# Combine Array of objects

Tags: android

I have an array of objects (I.E. 36 hours of weather data). Several of these objects share a common value (I.E. Days of the week). I need to combine these objects so that all the hourly weather data for each day is in one object.  How can I do this?

Comment: Build a data structure to house your data?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class for your weather, lets say `HourOfWeather` which contain the hour of day informations:

```
class HourOfWeather{
    public String temperature;
    public String time;
    public String dayOfTheWeek;
    ....
}
```

Then load your whole data in HashMap: `HashMap<String, ArrayList<HourOfWeather>>`.

- The HashMap key (String) will represent your Day.
- The HashMap value (`ArrayList<HourOfWeather>`) will represent your list of weather hours for that day.

Comment: I have tried adding the items into a hashmap in a for loop, but since the values have the same names, they just replace each other.  my ultimate goal is defined in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020858/i-cant-break-this-array-down) question which has not been answered.  I can't figure out what I am missing.

Comment: Don't add directly the items ithe HashMap. Lets say you have data for 3 days, **1)** Create 3 *ArrayList<HourOfWeather>* -- **2)** Loop your data , compare the "mDay" field and add each *hourOfWether* , in his corresponding ArraysList... now you have 3 ArrayLists that represent your days -- **3)** Add them to your HashMap, using "mDay" ( or any other unique value) as key.